# How to have bigger text in Windows Explorer only?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, appearance

I am running Windows 7 with recommended resolution of 1366x768. I am finding the font in explorer really small and painful. If I increase the font size from control panel EVERY software gets an ugly huge window. More than ugliness, they take up space and working is very painful, especially in apps like Visual Studio with hardly any document space at all.

Is there a solution to my pain?

Comment: "Control +" doesn't do the job?

Comment: No. Ctrl+ won't do anything. Using ctrl and mouse wheel changes the view type and cycles through details, list, icons etc.

Comment: Hmm, a lot of programs let you choose a font (though most use the system default). I have to admit that I am surprised that Explorer does not let you choose a font or size or anything. Have you tried using the DPI scaling instead of changing the font? That works different from just using a bigger font, so that might give you the the effect you want. Right-click the desktop, select *Screen Resolution → Advanced settings → 125% → Apply*. Also consider increasing the system text size, but then *reducing* the font in other programs like VS which do support setting a font.

Comment: I tried several things but they all end with the same result. The biggest problem with big windows is a lot of screen space is taken up by non client areas forcing me to have tiny fonts if I need more than like 6 lines of text. Seems tiny fonts *have* to happen somewhere. What kind of a stupid conservation law is this?